# Referring to Self '$' in Embedded Expressions in Karate

Tags: karate

probably a silly question.
I am trying to make use of self '$' when defining/reading a json.

```
  * def x = {a:1,b:{c:'#($.a)'},d:2}
  * print x
```

It fails.

```json
"a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": "#($.a)"
  },
  "d": 2
}
```

Is it possible to do something like above? At the time of defining variable, when the compiler reaches 'c', 'a' has already been defined. So, I am hopeful that it might be possible.

But I do understand there are edge cases of cyclic reference (referring '$') or referring something that is not yet defined('$.d'), but those cases can be handled to throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `$` magic variable is designed only for use within a `match`, like this:

```
* def x = { a: 1, b: { c: 1 }, d: 2 }
* match x contains { b: { c: '#($.a)' } }
```

That said, maybe you should do this:

```
* def val = 1
* def x = { a: '#(val)', b: { c: '#(val)' }, d: 2 }
* match x == { a: 1, b: { c: 1 }, d: 2 }
```

Note that you can always "build" JSON using JS snippets like this:

```
* def x = { a: 1, d: 2 }
* x.b = { c: x.a }
* match x == { a: 1, b: { c: 1 }, d: 2 }
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware by referring to a variable/json that is already defined, we can acheive it but I had a json defined in a file, and i was looking for a way where at the time I use def x= read(json) command, I was hoping it resolves calls made to self. I guess it's impractical what I am asking. :p 
Even in match statements,
* match x contains { b: { c: '#($.a)' } }
 self - '$' works because it refers to 'x' - a defined variable in scope.
Anyways, thanks for quick reply!